# Emulator process for AVD <device-name> has terminated while running Android App on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

After scaffolding an Android project and setting up an AVD device, I then tried to run the android app in the starter project for `Basic View Activity` but I keep getting this error -> `emulator process for AVD <device-name> has terminated`.

I tried to download a different system image for an Android Virtual Device (Pixel 2) but the same error returns. I am using the latest Android Studio 2023.2.1